# Rat proofing lawn in the city

Tags: pest-control, rodents

We live in the city and have a roughly 10' by 10' grass/dirt area. Rats are living/nesting in it and there are burrows everywhere. How can I redo the area in such a way that it's rat proof? I'm really trying to avoid cementing/paving it or filling it complete with stones/gravel.

Has anyone used http://www.wildlifecontrolsupplies.com/animal/XG900.html? It sounds promising, though expensive. I'm thinking about trying just that.

My other idea was to dig out about 18" and dump about 12" of stone and then put just 6" or so of dirt on the top for the grass.

Or I could do a combo. Stone, then Xcluder Geo frabic and then dirt.

I'm looking for feedback on the above ideas and other ideas. Cost and time to implement are definitely a concern, but most importantly I want something that works well and permanently. I might do it myself, but am open to hiring someone if I can find the right company for the job.

Note that we're in the city, a restaurant is nearby, and there are neighbors with rat problems too. I know that I can't solve all these problems, but I think I can at least prevent them from living in our yard. We have two kids and I'd like them to be able to play out there safely (no fear of rats jumping out of the ground, which has happened to me multiple times when digging).

Comment: Fabric and dirt over is not good!  How deep is the soil on your roof?  Have you considered crushed, compacted granite with small trees planted in pots?  I'd put fabric over the top of the soil in the pots as well as the hole in the bottom...make it so that you are able to remove and replace as needed to prevent the pots becoming condos.  Kids LOVE the texture of crushed granite and can imagine and play like crazy. Grass is over rated especially with that kind of infestation.  How old are your kids?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This is on the yard; not on my roof.

Comment: OOOKKK.  Then absolutely NOT.  What you are doing is the exact opposite of what the land, soils, your plants need.  Rats, will not hurt your plants...well, they'll eat your vegeys but to do this is just wrong for plants.  Gotta get your neighbors to stop being slovenly with garbage.  Rat will be there no matter what if there is a garbage source.  To include climbing up brick walls and swimming 100's of yards underwater to come up through the pipes and some come up through the toilet.  Cool creatures.  Poison and traps are flat out ridiculous.  That only makes their litters larger.